# show and hide content based on if someone has “liked” your facebook fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a `FAN PAGE` that makes LOTS of uploads to my `ALBUM`.
I DONT want to spam the people who `LIKED` my page with every upload

question: how can i control which images get viewed on my **fans** `WALL`?
In other words, if JOE was a fan to my `FAN PAGE` i dont want JOE's wall to be bombarded with fan page images.
Is this even possible using `GRAPH API`?

Answer (score 1):

Joe's wall would not be bombarded with images as a fan of your page. If you mean that his feed would be filled with the images, Facebook's algorithm for skimming through feed content ensures that your images do not instantly flood his wall. Rather, it ranks existing content from various sources and places a limit on how much content is shown per source.

Comment: could my `FAN PAGE` control which images get priority?

Comment: Yes, upload the content you wish to push out first, followed by the remaining media.

Comment: but there will be a steady stream of image uploaded to `FAN PAGE`'s album all day, evereyday

Comment: As stated before, Facebook's algorithm would disallow spammy behaviour. It would not get past their filter.